# "Rollbacked" or "rolled back" the edit? And what about "double-click"?

Tags: past-tense, compounds, orthography

The noun (and verb) ***[rollback](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rollback)*** on Stack Exchange means to undo or reverse an edit. I'm not sure if there is a difference between the two, but that's how I understand it.

Recently, I posted the past participle **rollbacked**,  in a comment, and after a bit I looked at it and realised I should have written **rolled back**.

The problem is that  **rollback** is spelt as one word, so adding the suffix -ed was an automatic gesture. And if I think about it, *backed* is an adjective, and *[back](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/back)* is also a verb.  Here's another example,  **double-click**, is the past tense *doubled-click* or *double-clicked*?

Was I so wrong to write *rollbacked*?

Why should it have been *rolled back* (two words)?

Are there cases of compound nouns (and verbs) where either the first noun/verb or the second can be placed in the simple past tense with no changing in meaning? I can't think of any on the top of my head.

Comment: Here's another quirk of the language: <strike>on</strike> "*off* the top of my head".

Comment: `off the top of my head` oops. Thanks @Lawrence. But I might leave that error, because I liked your comment :)

Comment: Compare *login* but *logged in*.

Comment: @snailplane but the beauty of "rollback" and "double-click" is that *back* and *double* are also verbs. By the way, is there some tag I should add?

Comment: @Mari-LouA *Back* is sometimes a verb, but *rollback* is a verb–preposition compound, not a verb–verb compound.  I can't think of any tags to add that you haven't already added to the question.

Comment: Back is an adverb, not a preposition.

Comment: I would say that as a verb, "rollback" is a misspelling. The correct spelling would be "roll back". Likewise, the verbs "turn off" and "log in" should not be spelled as "turnoff" or "login".

Comment: @TannerSwett This is a very common orthographic characteristic of English. I have a children's book from 1966 where the word *arm-chair* is hyphenated, who sees it spelled like that nowadays? So this joining up of two words into one, is very common, and *backroll*, I meant *rollback* is not a misspelling at all.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Tenses always apply to verbs, so to see where to apply it, you need to figure out which part of the compound (or hyphenated) word is the verb.

"Rollback" is a compound word, consisting of the verb "roll" and the preposition "back", as Peter indicated. As such, "rolling" is what you are doing, and "back" indicates where you're rolling (as opposed to rolling forward).

"Rollbacked" would imply that "back" is the verb, as in "to support". Unless you're supporting the edit with a cinnamon roll or used said cinnamon roll to move it back, this is not correct.

A converse compound word would be "backup" -- here, "back" is the verb and "up" is the preposition (see the [etymology of 'backup'](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=back%20up) in its non-compounded form). You haven't "backupped" the files, you've "backed up" the files.

With regards to double-click, "double" is the adverb that modifies the verb "click", so "double-clicked" is the correct form. I can see this possibly being confusing because it could be seen that you're "doubling" the click (or past tense, you "doubled" the click); however, when you tell someone to single click, you just say "click the button", and thus it becomes more obvious that click is the verb here.

Comment: Side note: rolling forward is a valid thing with respect to edits. It's what you do when someone erroneously rolls something back. Interestingly, I've never seen "rollforward" as a compound. Also, other prepositions generally don't work in the context of edits, except maybe "roll into", which I've also never seen compounded.

Answer (score 24):

In your examples

> rollback

is a compound word consisting of the verb *to roll* and the preposition *back*.

It is similar to

> [turnoff](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/turnoff)

which is composed of *to turn* and *off*.

The past tenses are

> rolled back
>   turned off

You may be confusing the nouns with the similar sounding verb phrases

> Q: Did you roll back the rollback of the databases?
>   A: Yes, we *rolled back* the databases to before the update.
>
> Q: I took the wrong turnoff and got lost.
>   I *turned off* the wrong exit.
>
> Walmart is *rolling back* their prices to be the same as several years ago.

[image: here]

In the case of

> double-click

the implied verb is "click", and the past tense is

> double-clicked
>
> She double-clicked on the "send" button after proofreading her email.

Comment: "Did you roll back the rollback of the databases?" This would be asking if you *undid* the rollback itself, restoring the databases back to the state they were in before the rollback. The response you have suggests that you meant something more like, "Did you roll back the databases?" or "Did you do the database rollback?"

Comment: 'back' is an adverb here, not a preposition.

Comment: @TonyK I agree. 1a I looked at the edit. 1b I looked at it. 1c At what did you look? 2a I rolled back the edit. 2b \*I rolled back it. 2c \*Back what did you roll?

Comment: *I rolled the transaction back*.  In contemporary grammar, **back** without complement would be considered an intransitive preposition; with complement (e.g. "rolled it back *to its former state*"), a transitive one.

Answer (score 2):

According to https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rollback, "rollback" can be either a noun or a verb, and "rollbacked" is presumably the correct past tense of that verb.

But in BrE, I would have written "rolled back" in the OP's example. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/roll gives "Roll something back" as a phrasal verb. By analogy with a word like "rollnecked", "rollbacked" seems like the adjective derived from the noun "rollback", not the past tense a the verb. (But https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/roll-neck gives "roll-neck" with a hyphen...)

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/double-click says "double-click" is a verb, and its past tense would logically be "double-clicked" - though the reference only gives examples in the present tense. A "doubled-click" seems like a noun (i.e. a particular sort of click), but I don't think the word is actually used.

For similar computing terms like "shift-click", "Alt-click", forms like "shifted-click" and "Alted-click" would be very strange, compared with the usual "shift-clicked" or "Alt-clicked".

Comment: "double", "alt", and "shift" are functioning more-or-less adverbially in those examples. It's always the verb that gets inflected (as the other answers say), and that would be "click".

Comment: I disagree that "rollbacked" is correct. The verb is "to roll back" with roll back as 2 words. The *noun* is rollback, 1 word. Therefore the plural nou is rollbacks, but the past tense verb is "rolled back".

Comment: I agree with @WendiKidd: just because a compound word is categorized as a verb or a noun doesn't mean that you can just stick -ed or -s at the end.  For example, the plural of passerby is passersby (and likewise for mother-in-law).